# Does it exist feature selection/reduction techniques in $O(n \cdot d)$?

Tags: feature-selection, feature-reduction

I'm curious to know if feature selection and/or feature reduction techniques exist, which are linear on number of data $n$ and on number of dimensions $d$.

References and source code are very welcome.

Comment: How about a t-test?